# PHP JSON file_put_contents blank

Tags: php, json

This is my current JSON file:

```
{"coins":"0","uses":"0"}
```

...and I rewrite the values with the following PHP:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('test.json'), true);
$data["coins"] = iconv($data["coins"] + $coins);
$data["uses"] = iconv($data["uses"] + 1);
file_put_contents('test.json', json_encode($data));
```

I've printed out the value of `$data` and have seen that it contains the new values. Yet, the file that `file_put_contents` writes to always ends up being blank. Any suggestions on why this is so?

**EDIT:**

This is what `$data` returns:

```
Array ( [coins] => 100 [uses] => 1 )
```

After changing up my code a little bit, it seems like `file_put_contents` returns `false`. Nevertheless, I have set the file permissions to **777** (`test.json`).

Comment: What does the return value of the `file_put_contents()` call say? `true` or `false`? I assume `false` which leads in most cases to insufficent write privileges granted by the system for the user which is running PHP.

Comment: Probably you are lack writing permission to the target file/destination?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER: insufficient privilege cannot be the source of the problem, since the file is opened, and the previous content is erased.

Comment: @up No you are right its because of wrong usage for iconv. $data may contain null because of the wrong usage of "iconv" the json structure might be malformed and json_encode might return null. null can evaluate to an empty string in php so its possible that file_put_contents overwrites the whole content with nothing because FILE_APPEND flag is not set if parameter flags is missing.

Comment: Why are you using iconv in the first place? In your case, iconv is useless.

Comment: Did you check what `json_encode($data)` generates? Maybe it returns false.

Comment: yeah please show us what ``json_encode($data)`` contains

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER `file_put_contents()` returns `false`. However, the file permissions is 777.

Comment: as timesplinter pointed out. ``$data`` contains data and ``file_put_contents`` return false which is for sure a permission problem. please check if the php user have write access to the file .

Answer (score -2):

No need for `iconv()` the following should do:

```
$data["coins"] = $data["coins"] + $coins;
$data["uses"] =$data["uses"] + 1;
```

if you dump the object you will see:

```
array(2) { ["coins"]=> string(1) "0" ["uses"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

They are strings because in your json the numbers have quotes around them.

if anything you can cast `(int)$data["coins"]` but fortunately php is smart enough to convert to the right data type.

`iconv()` is used more for converting string encoding.

Comment: I just learned this from other nice people :) "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post."

Comment: Yeah, that comment totally showed my PHP knowledge ;) You are right :)